# OLE Controls are not getting loaded in windows server 2012

Tags: mfc, ole, windows-server-2012, win32ole

I have a Win32 application which displays all types of controls like,

textboxes, radio buttons, images, OLE controls and list boxes.

That Win32 application is working fine in Windows 7 & 8.1 but not in Windows server 2012.

The OLE controls are not loaded in the application.

What might be the reason?

Thanks in advance

Comment: They are not registered? What is the HRESULT code when they should be created? Just debug... (you may debug remotely)

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue where my InstallShield package was not executing the script that registers the ActiveX controls. I registered the controls manually and everything worked fine after that.